# Number of processes changes midway

Tags: c, mpi, openmpi

I wrote a simple MPI program that takes an input file and take the first 99 numbers inside it, and sum them up. It's actually a slight modified version of [this](http://www.jaist.ac.jp/%7Eyaz/sp2/mpi_1.html). This programs works.

```c
#include "mpi.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#define MAXSIZE 99 //line 5

void main(int argc, char **argv){
        //int MAXSIZE = 6; //line 8
        int myid, numprocs;
        int data[MAXSIZE], i, x, low, high, myresult, result;
        char fn[255];
        FILE *fp;

        //if (argc > 1) MAXSIZE = atoi(argv[1]); //line 14
        MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
        MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid);

        if (myid == 0){ //Open input file and initialize data
                strcpy(fn, getenv("HOME"));
                strcat (fn, "/MPI/rand_data.txt");
                if ((fp = fopen(fn, "r")) == NULL){
                        printf("Can't open the input file: %s\n\n", fn);
                        exit (1);
                }
                for(i = 0; i < MAXSIZE; i++){
                        fscanf(fp,"%d", &data[i]);
                }
        }

        //broadcast data
        MPI_Bcast (data, MAXSIZE, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        //Add my portion Of data

        x = MAXSIZE/numprocs; //must be an integer
        low = myid * x;
        high = low + x;
        myresult = 0;

        for(i = low; i < high; i++){
                myresult += data[i];
        }
        if (MAXSIZE % numprocs > myid)
                myresult += data[x*numprocs+myid];
        printf("I got %d from %d\n", myresult, myid);

        //Compute global sum
        MPI_Reduce(&myresult, &result, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        if (myid == 0) printf("The sum is %d.\n", result);
        MPI_Finalize();

}
```

I then tried to make the same program takes argument (how many numbers it read and sums up) by simply commenting out line 5, and uncomment line 8 and 14. This program runs just fine with any argument, but passing 80 or above gives it weird behaviors. I did printf-style debugging, and found out that `numprocs`'s value, originally 4, will change to 1 in the middle of the process.

What happened here?

Comment: The value of `numprocs` changes when you overwrite it in `fscanf(fp,"%d", &data[i]);` when `i` is `6` or some other value that makes `&data[i]` equal to `&numprocs`. Read about stack frames and buffer overflows to understand why.

Comment: PLease remove the OpenMP tag. This has nothing to do with OpenMP (which is *NOT* OpenMPI!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird behaviour can be due to the line 10 where `int data[MAXSIZE]` is declared with `MAXSIZE` set in line 8 (which is `6`). This is because line 15 again sets `MAXSIZE`. If it's greater than the initial `MAXSIZE` then it can lead to undefined behaviour (probably also segmentation fault) because `data` array will now be accessed with new `MAXSIZE`. So move `int data[MAXSIZE]` from line 10 to line 16.

As far as changing the value of `numprocs` in the middle of the execution, it **shouldn't** happen at all. The only instance where value of `numprocs` is assigned (`write`) is during the MPI call and rest of the time it is only accessed (`read`). So in theory it shouldn't happen.

Comment: The other instance where `numprocs` is assigned to is when writing to `data[]` past its bounds, i.e., a typical case of stack smashing in combination with unlucky stack frame layout.